# Angular testing router params breaks test bed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I provide params to my `TestComponent` the test bed blows up if the html contains a `[routerLink]`

**testbed setup**

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [SharedModule.forRoot(), ManagementModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot([{
            path: '', component: TestComponent
        }])],
        declarations: [TestComponent],
        providers: [
            BaseRequestOptions,
            MockBackend,
            {
                provide: Http, useFactory: function (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                },
                deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            },
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
            {
                provide: ActivatedRoute,
                useValue: {
                    params: Observable.of({ versionId: '1' }),
                    parent: {
                        params: Observable.of({ uniqueId: '1234' })
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
});
```

**Error logged**

```
Failed: Error in ./DetailComponent class DetailComponent - inline template:72:20 caused by: Cannot read property '_lastPathIndex' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_lastPathIndex' of undefined
    at findStartingPosition (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/create_url_tree.js:184:0 <- src/test.ts:100429:23)
    at createUrlTree (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/create_url_tree.js:27:21 <- src/test.ts:100272:45)
    at Router.createUrlTree (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/router.js:424:0 <- src/test.ts:28688:111)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.get [as urlTree] (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/directives/router_link.js:253:0 <- src/test.ts:50778:32)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.updateTargetUrlAndHref (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/directives/router_link.js:246:0 <- src/test.ts:50771:91)
    at RouterLinkWithHref.ngOnChanges (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/router/src/directives/router_link.js:217:67 <- src/test.ts:50742:74)
    at Wrapper_RouterLinkWithHref.ngDoCheck (/RouterModule/RouterLinkWithHref/wrapper.ngfactory.js:101:18)
    at DebugAppView.View_DetailComponent3.detectChangesInternal (/ManagementModule/DetailComponent/component.ngfactory.js:548:33)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0 <- src/test.ts:95635:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0 <- src/test.ts:95830:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_container.js:67:0 <- src/test.ts:95967:37)
    at DebugAppView.View_DetailComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/ManagementModule/DetailComponent/component.ngfactory.js:85:14)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0 <- src/test.ts:95635:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///home/developer/Projects/project/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0 <- src/test.ts:95830:44)
```

**template line 72**

```
<a class="button" [routerLink]="['/']">Back</a>
```

In an ideal world i'd like to continue providing the params, any idea why its blowing up?

Comment: Please add the DetailsComponent code.

Comment: I am going to add the code now, but if you look, its complaining about the inline template and the line is in the question above, as i say, if you remove the line from the template it behaves correctly.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem as well. It seems to be related to ActivatedRoute. The error is only present when I involve ActivatedRoute.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I figured out the problem/solution.

We're seeing `Cannot read property '_lastPathIndex' of undefined` because at one point the Angular router expects a `_lastPathIndex` property on a `snapshot` object.

The relevant part of the [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L145) looks like this:

```
if (route.snapshot._lastPathIndex === -1) {
  return new Position(route.snapshot._urlSegment, true, 0);
}
```

If `snapshot` is undefined, it will of course raise the error we're seeing.

The problem can be solved by making `snapshot` not-undefined.

Here's how I did it. My code is a little different from the OP's.

I have a class called `MockActivatedRoute` that looks like this.

```
export class MockActivatedRoute {
  parent: any;
  params: any;

  constructor(options) {
    this.parent = options.parent;
    this.params = options.params;
  }
}
```

Here's how I use it in my test.

```
let mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({
  parent: new MockActivatedRoute({
    params: Observable.of({ id: '1' })
  })
});
```

To make the error go away I just added a `snapshot` property to `MockActivatedRoute`.

```
export class MockActivatedRoute {
  parent: any;
  params: any;
  snapshot = {};

  constructor(options) {
    this.parent = options.parent;
    this.params = options.params;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try when i get in the office tomorrow

Comment: No problem! If you can click accept on my answer, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add something similar to providers:

providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 1 }]), 'snapshot': {}} },
      ]

Comment: @DanDan your comment is spot on!

Comment: This saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

You can add **snapshot** property inside your providers array.

```
providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { snapshot: {} } }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add snapshot to your ActivatedRoute, useValue Object alongside params.

```
    providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            params: of({ id: 'test' }),
            snapshot: {}
          }
        },
      ]
```

Answer (score -2):

This works with no errors and no hack

```
import {
    TestBed,
    async
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    HttpModule,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    Http
} from '@angular/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import {
    RouterModule,
    ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
fdescribe( 'AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            imports      : [
                HttpModule,
                RouterModule.forRoot(
                    [
                        {
                            path      : '',
                            component : TestComponent
                        }
                    ] )
            ],
            declarations : [ TestComponent ],
            providers    : [
                BaseRequestOptions,
                MockBackend,
                {
                    provide    : Http,
                    useFactory : function ( backend : MockBackend, defaultOptions : BaseRequestOptions ) {
                        return new Http( backend, defaultOptions );
                    },
                    deps       : [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ]
                },
                {
                    provide  : APP_BASE_HREF,
                    useValue : '/'
                },
                {
                    provide  : ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue : {
                        params : Observable.of( { versionId : '1' } ),
                        parent : {
                            params : Observable.of( { uniqueId : '1234' } )
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        } );
        TestBed.compileComponents();
    } );
    it( 'should create the app', async( () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent( TestComponent );
        let app     = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect( app ).toBeTruthy();
    } ) );
} );

@Component( {
    selector    : 'app-root',
    template : `
        <a class="button" [routerLink]="['/']">Back</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

`,
} )
export class TestComponent {

}
```