# Cannot Read Property '_lastPathIndex' of Undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, router

I am mocking Activated route in my component spec like this :

```
class ActvatedRouterMock {
  public paramMap = of(convertToParamMap({
    level: 'customer',
    id: '12345',
  }));
}
```

Adding this class in providers section as well.

But when I run my test case I am getting the error
Cannot Read Property `_lastPathIndex` of Undefined

Version: Angular8
Any one can help me on resolving this ?

Comment: need to see more of your code.. the test itself, providing section, ..

Comment: According to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245783/angular-testing-router-params-breaks-test-bed) you should set in your ActvatedRouterMock an empty snapshot object.

Answer (score 4):

Probably in your production code you have something like:

```
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {
      relativeTo: this.route
    });
```

Then you need to provide a `snapshot` property to your activated route.

Example:

```
class ActvatedRouterMock {
  public paramMap = of(convertToParamMap({
    level: 'customer',
    id: '12345',
  }));
  public snapshot = new ActivatedRouteSnapshot();
}
```